# Separate word from number in R

Tags: r

How to create space between word and number? I have searched SO throughout but nothing was coming up for R.

I have dataframe like this:

```
1 This is the case34
2 To to that case23/234
3 Only Monday223.23
```

Desired output:

```
1 "This is the","case 34"
2 "To to that","case 23/234"
3 "Only","Monday 223.23"
```

So separate number from word, how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `read.table` and `sub` like this:

```
# data in reproducible form
DF <- data.frame(s=c("This is the case34", "To to that case23/234", "Only Monday223.23"))

read.table(text = sub("(.*\\S) ([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d.+)$", "\\1,\\2 \\3", DF$s), sep = ",")
```

which gives this data frame:

```
           V1            V2
1 This is the       case 34
2  To to that   case 23/234
3        Only Monday 223.23
```

Please provide your data in reproducible form next time.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry. Will do next time! Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for any character preceding a number as well

```
gsub("(\\D)([0-9])","\\1 \\2","papà3")
[1] "papà 3"
```

EDIT:

in response to @Max comment the double space problem it's solved using `[[:alpha:]]`, (as in G. Grothendieck answer)

```
> gsub("([[:alpha:]])([0-9])","\\1 \\2","This is the case 34")
[1] "This is the case 34"
> gsub("([[:alpha:]])([0-9])","\\1 \\2","This is the case34")
[1] "This is the case 34"
```

It will work for accents (like `papà3` above) and not for punctuation (`\\D` would), which is probably not wanted by the OP.

Comment: Works great! Just only thing is that I'm getting occasinally double spaces where i.e. "This is the case 34" is correct. So I get "This is the case  34" double space.

Comment: @Max that's because \\D includes spaces as well... mmm probably it's not the best choice. You could wrap the result and remove double spaces. But there is certainly a better answer

Answer (score 1):

Yu can use regular expressions for this task. This should work:

```
x<-c('This is the case34','To to that case23/234','Only Monday223.23')
gsub('([A-Za-z])([0-9])','\\1 \\2',x)
# [1] "This is the case 34"    "To to that case 23/234" "Only Monday 223.23"
```

But if you have characters with accents in it, you'll have to take care of that by adding more possibilities to the set of letters. If you wanted to also put space between numbers followed by a letter, you could just do a second pass and reverse the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `lapply` and regexpr :

```
x <- c("This is the case34", "To to that case23/234", "Only Monday223.23")
(xx <- lapply(strsplit(x, split=" "), function(x) c(paste(x[!grepl(pattern="\\d",
x=x)], collapse=" "), paste(gsub('([A-Za-z])([0-9])','\\1 \\2', x[grepl(pattern="\\d",
x=x)]), collapse=" "))))

[[1]]
[1] "This is the" "case 34"    

[[2]]
[1] "To to that"  "case 23/234"

[[3]]
[1] "Only"          "Monday 223.23"

do.call("rbind", xx)
     [,1]          [,2]           
[1,] "This is the" "case 34"      
[2,] "To to that"  "case 23/234"  
[3,] "Only"        "Monday 223.23"
```